# what gets returned when you return self?

Tags: python, python-3.x

what gets returned when you return 'self' inside a python class?  where do we exactly use return 'self'? In the below example what does self exactly returns

```
class Fib:
'''iterator that yields numbers in the Fibonacci sequence'''

    def __init__(self, max):
        self.max = max

    def __iter__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 1
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        fib = self.a
        if fib > self.max:
            raise StopIteration
        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a + self.b
        print(self.a,self.b,self.c)
        return fib
```

Answer (score 3):

Python treats method calls like `object.method()` approximately like `method(object)`. [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects) say that "call `x.f()` is exactly equivalent to `MyClass.f(x)`". This means that a method will receive the object as the first argument. By convention in the definition of methods, this first argument is called `self`.

So `self` is the conventional name of the object owning the method.

Now, why would we want to return `self`? In your particular example, it is because the object implements the [iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types), which basically means it has `__iter__` and `__next__` methods. The `__iter__` method must (according to the docs) "Return the iterator object itself", which is exactly what is happening here.

As an aside, another common reason for returning `self` is to support [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining), where you would want to do `object.method1().method2().method3()` where all those methods are defined in the same class. This pattern is quite common in libraries like pandas.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `self` is used to refer to the instance that you are calling the method from.

This is particularly useful for [chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining#Python). In your example, let's say we want to call `__next__()` on an initialized `Fib` instance. Since `__iter__()` returns `self`, the following are equivalent :

```
obj = Fib(5)
obj.__iter__() # Initialize obj 
obj.__next__()
```

And

```
obj = Fib(5).__iter__() # Create AND initialize obj
obj.__next__()
```

In your particular example, the `self` keyword returns the instance of the `Fib` class from which you are calling `__iter__()` (called `obj` in my small snippet).

Hope it'll be helpful.

Comment: Except that `__next__()` doesn't return `self` (nor should it, if you want to support the iteration protocol).

Comment: Apologies, just modified my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Note that `self` is not a keyword, just a conventional name for the first argument. Python would not stop you from using a different name.

Answer (score 0):

[Partial Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144452/is-it-okay-to-put-partial-answers):

When you return `self`, you return the class instance. For example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def ret_self(self):
        return self
```

If I create an instance and run `ret_self`, you will see that they both refer to the same instance:

```
>>> x = Foo("a")
>>> x
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x0000000002823D48>
>>> x.ret_self()
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x0000000002823D48>
```

In other words, both `x` and `x.ret_self()` return the same reference to that class instance.

`self` is actually another way of saying "this instance of `Foo`". Hence, instance variables are `self.a` in the class.

When will you need this? I don't have the experience to tell you and I do not want to give possibly misleading information that I am unsure of. I will leave it to someone else to expound on this answer.

**Please do not accept this answer.**

Comment: Can you explain in the fib class what does "self" exactly returns. Is it returning the value of self.a and self.b?

Comment: In my example, `x.ret_self()` literally returns the `x`. `x` references the class instance. `x.ret_self()` references the class instance. So you could do `x.ret_self().a` and still get `"a"`.

Comment: Ok I understand but what is the use of literally returning a reference of a class

Comment: IMO, I would see no use in that but I may be wrong. As I said in my post "I don't have the experience to tell you and I do not want to give possibly misleading information that I am unsure of. I will leave it to someone else to expound on this answer."